# If a Stream is fed to the Slick batch insert then does it materialize the whole stream?

Tags: scala, slick

I've tried to quickly insert some 100M records to MySQL table with help of Slick.
Naively I've expected that if I provide a test data set as a `Stream` then Slick will work with it not greedy:

```
val testData = Stream.continually(
        UUIDRecord(uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString, value = (Math.random()*100).toLong)
      ).take(100000000)
 val batchInsert:DBIO[Option[Int]] = records ++= testData
 val insertResult = db.run(batchInsert)
```

But I think I have miscalculated and Slick anyway materializes the stream before passing it to the MySQL because I am getting this error when running:

```
#
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000b9700000, 281542656, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 281542656 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /ssd2/projects/StreamingDB/hs_err_pid28154.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you advice? I know that Slick can run queries in streaming mode (i.e. it is a reactive-streams publisher), but is there any way to insert large amount of records in "streaming" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may be interested in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1272). In short, batch mode requires support from the JDBC driver.

Even assuming batch mode is enabled for you, it is still most probably will not work as you expect. Unfortunately you didn't provide actual stack trace for your OOM but I bet it is inside `MultiInsertAction.run` and more specifically inside the [`st.addBatch()`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcActionComponent.scala#L529) call where `st` is a subclass of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. And the problem is that even in the batch mode, the batch must be first accumulated. In other words the client should accumulate all the data that will be passed as a part of the `INSERT` statement and this requires actually materializing it in some form. So the point is that even if Slick does not materialize the stream, JDBC will.

The only workaround I can think of is to explicitly split your stream of data into some batches and insert those smaller batches. You may consider something like this:

```
val testData = Stream.continually(
  UUIDRecord(uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString, value = (Math.random()*100).toLong)
).take(100000000)

val BATCH_SIZE = 1000
val futures = testData.grouped(BATCH_SIZE).map(batch => {
  val batchInsert: DBIO[Option[Int]] = records ++= batch
  db.run(batchInsert)
})
val all: Future[Int] = Future.sequence(futures).map(it => it.map(_.getOrElse(0)).sum)
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented in a similar way as you proposed. And the issue at Github you've pointed at is interesting and informative.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar, if the answer does help, you may mark it as Accepted.